# Check if the number is even or odd

Tags: c

My program gives me error(not exactly an error but it just prints error instead of even or odd) even if I put a number or letters.  The code works if I remove the isdigit checker(3rd line). I do no know what am I doing wrong.  Can someone please help me.  Thanks in advance.  Here is my code.

```
int main()
{
   int n;

   printf("Input an integer\n");
   scanf("%d", &n);

   if(!isdigit(n))
   {
       print("error");
       return 0;
   }

   n%2 == 0 ? printf("Even\n") : printf("Odd\n");

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the **desired behavior**, a **specific** problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: "gives me error": obviously: **what** error? I mean, that's probably the answer to your question. Why do you think it's a good idea to omit that?

Comment: Use `if(scanf("%d", &n) != 1)` instead of `if(!isdigit(n))`

Comment: Have you included ctype.h library?

Comment: @CoolGuy can you please explain what if(scanf("%d", &n) != 1) does.  Thank you so much

Comment: @AP6 `scanf` returns the number of data successfully scanned and assigned. In your case, if `%d` was successful in scanning a number, `scanf` will return 1. Otherwise, if it fails, it will return 0 and on encountering `EOF`, it will return -1. So `if(scanf("%d", &n) != 1)` can be read as "*if `scanf` (or `%d`) was not successful*"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`isdigit` is not for this purpose.

If you want to check if the input is vaild, one method is to load with `%s` and use `strtol`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void print(const char *s) {
    puts(s);
}

int main()
{
    char nstr[100] = {0};
    int n;
    char *e;

    printf("Input an integer\n");
    scanf("%99s", nstr);

    n=(int)strtol(nstr, &e, 10);
    if(nstr[0] == '\0' || *e != '\0')
    {
        print("error");
        return 0;
   }

    n%2 == 0 ? printf("Even\n") : printf("Odd\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*`char nstr[100] = {};`*" -- This is C, not C++. Use `char nstr[100] = {0};` instead.

Comment: @CoolGuy This is `c` question, and this code [can be compiled as C++ with no warnings / errors.](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/2XUb0FLvLypSHSFH) Where is the source?

Comment: Oh. That compiles. But with `warning: ISO C forbids empty initializer braces [-Wpedantic]`

Comment: @CoolGuy I got it. You say that this code is valid as C++ but invalid as (ISO) C.

Answer (score 4):

> man -a isdigit

```
   isdigit()
          checks for a digit (0 through 9).
```

Thus isdigit fails if ascii value of n is not anything but

```
  Oct   Dec   Hex   Char
--------------------------
   060   48    30    0                           
   061   49    31    1                           
   062   50    32    2                           
   063   51    33    3                           
   064   52    34    4                           
   065   53    35    5                           
   066   54    36    6                           
   067   55    37    7                           
   070   56    38    8                           
   071   57    39    9
```

> man -a ascii

thus,

```
if(!isdigit(n))
   {
       print("error");
       return 0;
   }
```

is not an appropriate option. you should probably find some other option to validate n.

Answer (score 2):

The isdigit function checks a character to see if it is in the '0' to '9' range.  More specifically, it checks if the ASCII value of the character is between 48 (the code for '0') and 57 (the code for '9').

You're passing an int to this function, not a character, so it's not appropriate to use this function here.  Just remove this check and it will work.

Comment: "*Just remove this check and it will work.*" -- The OP probably wants "error" to be printed when the user enters anything that is not a number.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Please enter your number\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    if( n%2==0)
    printf("The number is even\n");
    else
    printf("The number is odd\n");


  System("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Check this one.